# Parent records Record type NAME on Activities

Tags: formula-field, activity

I have a custom requirement for which i was trying to get Parent objects record type Name on child object (Activities).

I can get it using Process Builder or trigger but is there anyway i can get this done using Formula. As process builder & trigger will get the value for new or updated records, but not for old not updated records.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Whose recordtype you want to know? Is that of `What` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Formula field we cannot access Recordtype or even other attributes from `What` object (Related To).

So, you need to create separate text field and during creation/updating of Task or Event, populate that field.

Update historical records through dataloader.